# Sitecore Add Event to calendar SxA

Tags: sxa

I have a template for events and I created items from these events. Then for each event item, I have event details which is a page that displays the details of the event, and it has a button "Add to Calendar".

I want to be able to automatically add this event to the default calendar of the user device (example: Outlook calendar, Google calendar,...) whenever he clicks on that button.

Any clue if there is a plugin that can do this for me or any other solution?

The solution is using SxA.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use Variant Template and construct there such link in NVelocity template:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=[event-title]&dates=[start-custom format='Ymd\\THi00\\Z']/[end-custom format='Ymd\\THi00\\Z']&details=[description]&location=[location]&trp=false&sprop=&sprop=name:" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Add to my calendar</a>
```

This should add an event to the callender on the google account you are currently logged in (I didn't test it, just found that fancy link somewhere).

You can also still use plugins like those:

- https://add.eventable.com/free-add-to-calendar-button
- https://www.addevent.com/add-to-calendar-button

Comment: Thanks Dawid for these links, it's really helpful. But i'm wondering if there is a way to do so without letting the user choose the calendar he wants to add the event to by automatically detecting the device default calendar and directly adding the event to it??